# Dispatch request to jsp page in specific folder

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("Admin/DeleteSuccess.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);
```

I want to dispatch the request to specified folder but it is not dispatching. It is still into the servlet.

Comment: What do you mean by this _but it is not dispatching. It is still into the servle_ ?

Comment: it should forward it to specified folder i.e Web Pages/Admin/Deletesuccess.jsp. and this servlet is present into sourcepackage/phone/PhoneDeleteServlet.java. when condition is true it is still present into current servlet

Comment: Did you get any error , post your project structure ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/testAARUS/Admin/Admin.jsp       http://localhost:8080/testAARUS/Admin/DeletePhones.jsp    http://localhost:8080/testAARUS/PhoneDeleteServlet?pid=1          <form  action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/PhoneDeleteServlet" >

Comment: what is the project structure?

Comment: try `response.sendRedirect("Admin/DeleteSuccess.jsp")`

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to the `deletesuccess` page,

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin/DeleteSuccess.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response)
```

Assuming `admin` is the folder under your project

Comment: yes there is a folder name admin in which the deletesuccess.jsp is present. i have to dispatch request from package phone/phonedeleteservlet.java to that admin/deletesuccess.jsp

Comment: If so , above code should work . does that redirect correctly ?

Comment: no it doesn't . but yes the content of destination page is displaying into the servlet rather than displaying into the jsp page

Comment: Did you mean that the `URL` in your browser remains the same ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 RequestDispatcher rd =getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("../admin/DeleteSuccess.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response)
```